# Why my capsule collider sometimes stucks in other colliders?

Tags: collision-detection, gameobject, rigidbody, scene

I'm creating a third person game, and sometimes I face a strange bug that I cannot figure out. Indeed the player may remain stuck in static scene objects, and cannot escape until an angle large enough in relation to the object is reached, as you can see in the small video below:

[image]

The player is composed by a **rigid body** and a **capsule collider**, and the settings are shown below:

[image]

The object shown in the above video, which stuck the player, is **static** and contains a **sphere collider** but **no rigid body**.

I already tried to change the **collision detection** parameter in my player rigid body to **Continuous** or **Dynamically Continuous**, and to set a **physic material** with the **frictions set to 0** in the **colliders which stuck the player**, but although this improved the situation, the player still may sometimes be stuck in static objects.

I don't understand why this problem is happening and I don't know what else to do to fix it. So if someone may share info about how to fix that I would be grateful.

---

EDIT on 28.09.2020

here is, as requested, the source code used for the player's move. NOTE forgive me for the length, I tried to limit the code to the relevant part, but even thus it remains huge.

So below is the code of my player controller:

```cs
public class UFK_PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    public class IRotationController
    {
        public class IHead
        {
            public float m_Sensitivity     = 2.0f;
            public float m_MinAngle        = -45.0f;
            public float m_MaxAngle        = 89.5f;
            public bool  m_DoClampRotation = true;

            private Quaternion m_Rotation = new Quaternion();

            public Quaternion Rotation
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_Rotation;
                }

                set
                {
                    // limit the head rotation inside the human body acceptable limits
                    if (m_DoClampRotation)
                    {
                        m_Rotation = ClampRotation(value);
                        return;
                    }

                    m_Rotation = value;
                }
            }

            public void Init(Quaternion q)
            {
                m_Rotation = q;
            }

            Quaternion ClampRotation(Quaternion q)
            {
                q.x /= q.w;
                q.y /= q.w;
                q.z /= q.w;
                q.w  = 1.0f;

                float angle = Mathf.Clamp(2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(q.x), m_MinAngle, m_MaxAngle);
                q.x         = Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle);

                return q;
            }
        }

        public class IBody
        {
            public float m_Sensitivity = 2.0f;

            public Quaternion Rotation { get; set; }

            public void Init(Quaternion q)
            {
                Rotation = q;
            }
        }

        public IHead m_Head       = new IHead();
        public IBody m_Body       = new IBody();
        public bool  m_Smooth     = true;
        public float m_SmoothTime = 18.0f;

        public void Init(Transform head, Transform body)
        {
            // initialize the player rotations
            m_Head.Init(head.localRotation);
            m_Body.Init(body.localRotation);
        }

        public void Rotate(Transform head, Transform body, Vector2 axis, bool force)
        {
            // no rotation?
            if (!force && axis == Vector2.zero)
                return;

            // calculate the movements amplitude
            float headAmplitude = axis.y * m_Head.m_Sensitivity;
            float bodyAmplitude = axis.x * m_Body.m_Sensitivity;

            // calculate the resulting rotation
            m_Body.Rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, bodyAmplitude, 0.0f);
            m_Head.Rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-headAmplitude, 0.0f, 0.0f);

            // do apply smooth rotation?
            if (m_Smooth)
            {
                // calculate and apply smooth rotation
                head.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(head.localRotation, m_Head.Rotation, m_SmoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
                body.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(body.localRotation, m_Body.Rotation, m_SmoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                // apply rotation
                head.localRotation = m_Head.Rotation;
                body.localRotation = m_Body.Rotation;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ITranslationController
    {
        public float m_ForwardSpeed  = 8.0f;
        public float m_BackwardSpeed = 4.0f;
        public float m_SidewaySpeed  = 4.0f;
        public float m_RunMultiplier = 2.0f;
        public float m_JumpForce     = 50.0f;
        public AnimationCurve m_SlopeCurve = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(-90.0f, 1.0f),
                                                                new Keyframe(0.0f, 1.0f),
                                                                new Keyframe(90.0f, 0.0f));
        public float m_CurrentTargetSpeed = 8.0f;

        public bool Running { get; private set; }

        public void UpdateTargetSpeed(Vector2 dir, bool running)
        {
            // no direction?
            if (dir == Vector2.zero)
                return;

            // walking sideways?
            if (dir.x > 0.0f || dir.x < 0.0f)
                m_CurrentTargetSpeed = m_SidewaySpeed;

            // going backward or forward?
            if (dir.y < 0.0f)
                // backwards
                m_CurrentTargetSpeed = m_BackwardSpeed;
            else
            if (dir.y > 0.0f)
                // forwards. Handled last as if strafing and moving forward at the same time forwards speed should take precedence
                m_CurrentTargetSpeed = m_ForwardSpeed;

            Running = running;

            // is running?
            if (Running)
                m_CurrentTargetSpeed *= m_RunMultiplier;
        }
    }
    
    ...
    
    public delegate Vector2 OnGetRotationGestureEvent(object sender);

    public delegate Vector2 OnGetTranslationGestureEvent(object sender);

    public delegate bool OnGetJumpStatusEvent(object sender);

    public delegate bool OnGetRunStatusEvent(object sender);

    public delegate bool OnGetPausedStatusEvent(object sender);

    public delegate void OnCollisionEvent(object sender, Rigidbody rigidBody, Collider collider, Collision collision);

    public IRotationController    m_RotationController    = new IRotationController();
    public ITranslationController m_TranslationController = new ITranslationController();

    ...

    public float m_SlowDownRate                = 20.0f;
    public float m_ShellOffset                 = 0.1f;
    public float m_GroundCheckDistance         = 0.1f;
    public float m_StickToGroundHelperDistance = 0.6f;
    public bool  m_AirControl;
    public bool  m_FirstPerson = false;

    private readonly IModelController m_ModelController       = new IModelController();
    private readonly ISoundController m_SoundController       = new ISoundController();
    private readonly IViewStatus      m_FirstViewStatus       = new IViewStatus();
    private readonly IViewStatus      m_ThirdViewStatus       = new IViewStatus();
    private readonly CS_Dimmer        m_Dimmer                = new CS_Dimmer();
    private          Vector3          m_GroundContactNormal;
    private          float            m_DefHeadMaxAngle;
    private          bool             m_Running;
    private          bool             m_BackwardRunning;
    private          bool             m_WalkingLeft;
    private          bool             m_WalkingRight;
    private          bool             m_Jump;
    private          bool             m_PreviouslyGrounded;
    private          bool             m_Enabled               = true;
    private          bool             m_Suspended             = false;
    private          bool             m_CameraColliderEnabled = false;

    ...

    public GameObject Camera { get; private set; }

    public CS_CameraMotion CameraMotion { get; private set; }

    public CS_CameraCollider CameraCollider {  get; private set; }

    public Rigidbody RigidBody { get; private set; }

    public CapsuleCollider Collider { get; private set; }

    public Vector3 Velocity
    {
        get
        {
            return RigidBody.velocity;
        }
    }

    public Vector2 TranslationGesture { get; private set; }

    public Vector2 RotationGesture { get; private set; }

    public bool IsGrounded { get; private set; }

    public bool Jumping { get; private set; }

    public bool Running
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TranslationController.Running;
        }
    }

    public OnGetRotationGestureEvent OnGetRotationGesture { get; set; }

    public OnGetTranslationGestureEvent OnGetTranslationGesture { get; set; }

    public OnGetJumpStatusEvent OnGetJumpStatus { get; set; }

    public OnGetRunStatusEvent OnGetRunStatus { get; set; }

    public OnGetPausedStatusEvent OnGetPausedStatus { get; set; }

    public OnCollisionEvent OnCollision { get; set; }

    ...

    void Start()
    {
        // get the player components located around the script
        RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Collider  = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

        Debug.Assert(RigidBody);
        Debug.Assert(Collider);

        // get the child player camera
        Camera = GameObject.Find("Camera");
        Debug.Assert(Camera);

        // get the camera motion
        CameraMotion = Camera.GetComponent<CS_CameraMotion>();
        Debug.Assert(CameraMotion);

        // get the camera collider
        CameraCollider = Camera.GetComponent<CS_CameraCollider>();

        // found it?
        if (CameraCollider)
        {
            CameraCollider.OnCameraDistanceEvaluated = OnCameraDistanceEvaluated;
            m_CameraColliderEnabled                  = CameraCollider.enabled;
        }

        // initialize the view status
        m_FirstViewStatus.Init();
        m_ThirdViewStatus.Init(Camera, m_RotationController.m_Head);

        // configure the first person view, if required
        if (m_FirstPerson)
            m_FirstViewStatus.Apply(Camera, m_RotationController.m_Head);

        // initialize the player rotations
        m_RotationController.Init(Camera.transform, transform);

        // initialize the animation controller. NOTE if no model was found, the game may run without
        if (!m_ModelController.Init("Alexandra"))
            if (!m_ModelController.Init("Leonardo"))
                if (!m_ModelController.Init("Sandra"))
                    if (!m_ModelController.Init("William"))
                        if (!m_ModelController.Init("Yuna"))
                            if (!m_ModelController.Init("Yan"))
                                Debug.Log("No model found for player, the game will run without");

        // link the kick animation events
        if (m_ModelController.KickAnimController)
        {
            m_ModelController.KickAnimController.OnKickBall = OnKickBall;
            m_ModelController.KickAnimController.OnKickEnd  = OnKickEnd;
        }

        // initialize the player sounds
        m_SoundController.Init(GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>());

        // keep the head default max angle
        m_DefHeadMaxAngle = m_RotationController.m_Head.m_MaxAngle;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // is player disabled?
        if (!Enabled)
            return;

        // is player suspended?
        if (m_Suspended)
        {
            // keep the last model fade value
            float oldValue = m_Dimmer.Value;

            // calculate the next model fade value
            if (m_Dimmer.Value > m_MinAlphaValue)
                m_Dimmer.Value = m_Dimmer.Value - (10.0f * Time.deltaTime);
            else
                m_Dimmer.Value = m_MinAlphaValue;

            // if a new value was calculated, apply it
            if (m_Dimmer.Value != oldValue)
                m_ModelController.ChangeOpacity(m_Dimmer.Value);

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // keep the last model fade value
            float oldValue = m_Dimmer.Value;

            // calculate the next model fade value
            if (m_Dimmer.Value < 1.0f)
                m_Dimmer.Value = m_Dimmer.Value + (10.0f * Time.deltaTime);
            else
                m_Dimmer.Value = 1.0f;

            // if a new value was calculated, apply it
            if (m_Dimmer.Value != oldValue)
                m_ModelController.ChangeOpacity(m_Dimmer.Value);
        }

        // is game paused?
        if (GetPausedStatus() && !m_Jump)
            return;

        // get the rotation gesture
        RotationGesture = GetRotationGesture();

        // rotate the player in response to the mouse/touch events
        Rotate(RotationGesture, false);

        // check if the player should jump, and if not currently jumping, jump
        if (GetJumpStatus() && !m_Jump)
            m_Jump = true;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // is player disabled?
        if (!Enabled)
            return;

        // is player suspended?
        if (m_Suspended)
            return;

        // is game paused?
        if (GetPausedStatus())
            return;

        CheckGround();

        // get the translation gesture
        TranslationGesture = GetTranslationGesture();

        // apply translation and jump effect to player
        Translate(TranslationGesture);
        Jump(TranslationGesture);
    }

    Vector2 GetTranslationGesture()
    {
        // don't allow to move the player if camera is currently travelling
        if (CameraMotion.IsTravelling)
            return Vector2.zero;

        return OnGetTranslationGesture?.Invoke(this) ?? new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    }

    Vector2 GetRotationGesture()
    {
        // don't allow to rotate the player if camera is currently travelling
        if (CameraMotion.IsTravelling)
            return Vector2.zero;

        return OnGetRotationGesture?.Invoke(this) ?? new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
    }

    bool GetJumpStatus()
    {
        // don't allow the player to jump if camera is currently travelling
        if (CameraMotion.IsTravelling)
            return false;

        return OnGetJumpStatus?.Invoke(this) ?? (Input.GetAxis("Jump") != 0.0f);
    }

    bool GetRunStatus()
    {
        // don't allow the player to run if camera is currently travelling
        if (CameraMotion.IsTravelling)
            return false;

        return OnGetRunStatus?.Invoke(this) ?? (Input.GetAxis("Run") != 0.0f);
    }

    void Translate(Vector2 axis)
    {
        // apply the translation
        m_TranslationController.UpdateTargetSpeed(axis, GetRunStatus());

        m_Running         = false;
        m_BackwardRunning = false;
        m_WalkingLeft     = false;
        m_WalkingRight    = false;
        bool stillPlaying = false;

        // is the input value large enough to move the player, and the player is lying on the ground or can be controlled while jumping?
        if ((Mathf.Abs(axis.x) > float.Epsilon || Mathf.Abs(axis.y) > float.Epsilon) && (m_AirControl || IsGrounded))
        {
            // always move along the camera forward as it is the direction that it being aimed by the player
            Vector3 desiredMove = Camera.transform.forward * axis.y + Camera.transform.right * axis.x;
            desiredMove         = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desiredMove, m_GroundContactNormal).normalized;

            // calculate the desired move amplitude
            desiredMove.x *= m_TranslationController.m_CurrentTargetSpeed;
            desiredMove.y *= m_TranslationController.m_CurrentTargetSpeed;
            desiredMove.z *= m_TranslationController.m_CurrentTargetSpeed;

            // run the running animation
            if (IsGrounded)
            {
                // side walking
                if (axis.x > 0.0f)
                {
                    m_WalkingRight = true;

                    if (m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_DoKick &&
                        m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingRight)
                        m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingRight;
                }
                else
                if (axis.x < 0.0f)
                {
                    m_WalkingLeft = true;

                    if (m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_DoKick &&
                        m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingLeft)
                        m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingLeft;
                }

                // front or backward running
                if (axis.y > 0.0f)
                {
                    m_Running = true;

                    if (m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_DoKick &&
                        m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Running)
                        m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Running;
                }
                else
                if (axis.y < 0.0f)
                {
                    m_BackwardRunning = true;

                    if (m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_DoKick &&
                        m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_BackwardRunning)
                        m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_BackwardRunning;
                }
            }

            // do move the body?
            if (RigidBody.velocity.sqrMagnitude < (m_TranslationController.m_CurrentTargetSpeed * m_TranslationController.m_CurrentTargetSpeed))
            {
                // move the body by applying a force on it along the player direction
                RigidBody.AddForce(desiredMove * GetSlopeMultiplier(), ForceMode.Impulse);

                // play the footstep on concrete sound
                m_SoundController.Play((int)ISoundController.IEType.IE_T_FootSteps_Concrete);

                // keep the sound playing alive
                stillPlaying = true;
            }
        }

        // set animation to idle if no longer running
        if (m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_DoKick                                   &&
            ((!m_Running         && m_ModelController.AnimState == IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Running)         ||
             (!m_BackwardRunning && m_ModelController.AnimState == IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_BackwardRunning) ||
             (!m_WalkingLeft     && m_ModelController.AnimState == IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingLeft)     ||
             (!m_WalkingRight    && m_ModelController.AnimState == IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingRight)))
            // check if grounded, in case the jump was not performed by the user (e.g when he falls or hit an obstacle)
            if (IsGrounded)
                m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Idle;
            else
                m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Jumping;

        // don't allow single file footsteps to run infinitely
        if (!stillPlaying)
            m_SoundController.Stop((int)ISoundController.IEType.IE_T_FootSteps_Concrete);
    }

    void Rotate(Vector2 axis, bool force)
    {
        // avoid the mouse looking if the game is effectively paused
        if (Mathf.Abs(Time.timeScale) < float.Epsilon)
            return;

        // no rotation?
        if (!force && axis == Vector2.zero)
            return;

        // get the rotation before it's changed
        float oldYRotation = transform.eulerAngles.y;

        // get the player rotation, and apply it to the head and body
        m_RotationController.Rotate(Camera.transform, transform, axis, force);

        // is player grounded, or can player modify his rotation on jumping?
        if (IsGrounded || m_AirControl)
        {
            // rotate the rigidbody velocity to match the new direction that the character is looking
            Quaternion velRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(transform.eulerAngles.y - oldYRotation, Vector3.up);
            RigidBody.velocity     = velRotation * RigidBody.velocity;
        }
    }

    void Jump(Vector2 axis)
    {
        // is body currently lying on the ground?
        if (IsGrounded)
        {
            RigidBody.drag = 5.0f;

            // not already jumping?
            if (m_Jump)
            {
                Jumping = true;

                // apply the jump force
                RigidBody.drag     = 0.0f;
                RigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(RigidBody.velocity.x, 0.0f, RigidBody.velocity.z);
                RigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, m_TranslationController.m_JumpForce, 0.0f), ForceMode.Impulse);

                // run the jump animation
                if (m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_DoKick)
                    m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Jumping;
            }

            // mitigate the jump effect when the player lies again on the ground, and if he isn't running
            if (!Jumping && Mathf.Abs(axis.x) < float.Epsilon && Mathf.Abs(axis.y) < float.Epsilon && RigidBody.velocity.magnitude < 1.0f)
                RigidBody.Sleep();
        }
        else
        {
            RigidBody.drag = 0.0f;

            // if not jumping, check if the player is falling down a slope
            if (m_PreviouslyGrounded && !Jumping)
                StickToGround();
        }

        m_Jump = false;
    }

    float GetSlopeMultiplier()
    {
        return m_TranslationController.m_SlopeCurve.Evaluate(Vector3.Angle(m_GroundContactNormal, Vector3.up));
    }

    void StopBody()
    {
        RigidBody.velocity        = Vector3.zero;
        RigidBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void StickToGround()
    {
        // is player lying on the ground?
        if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position,
                               Collider.radius * (1.0f - m_ShellOffset),
                               Vector3.down,
                               out RaycastHit hitInfo,
                               ((Collider.height / 2.0f) - Collider.radius) + m_StickToGroundHelperDistance,
                               Physics.AllLayers,
                               QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            // is slope higher or equals to 85°?
            if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Angle(hitInfo.normal, Vector3.up)) < 85.0f)
                // applies the gravity force to the rigid body
                RigidBody.velocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(RigidBody.velocity, hitInfo.normal);
    }

    void CheckGround()
    {
        m_PreviouslyGrounded = IsGrounded;

        // sphere cast down just beyond the bottom of the capsule to see if the capsule is colliding around the bottom
        if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position,
                               Collider.radius * (1.0f - m_ShellOffset),
                               Vector3.down,
                               out RaycastHit hitInfo,
                               ((Collider.height / 2.0f) - Collider.radius) + m_GroundCheckDistance,
                               Physics.AllLayers,
                               QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
        {
            IsGrounded            = true;
            m_GroundContactNormal = hitInfo.normal;
        }
        else
        {
            IsGrounded            = false;
            m_GroundContactNormal = Vector3.up;
        }

        // jump ended?
        if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && IsGrounded && Jumping)
            Jumping = false;

        // reset the jump animation to idle or to the appropriate running animation if the jump ends
        if (m_ModelController.AnimState != IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_DoKick && !Jumping && IsGrounded &&
            m_ModelController.AnimState == IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Jumping)
            if (m_Running)
                m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Running;
            else
            if (m_BackwardRunning)
                m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_BackwardRunning;
            else
            if (m_WalkingLeft)
                m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingLeft;
            else
            if (m_WalkingRight)
                m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_WalkingRight;
            else
                m_ModelController.AnimState = IModelController.IEAnimState.IE_AS_Idle;
    }

    void OnCameraDistanceEvaluated(object sender, float distance, float minDistance, float maxDistance)
    {
        // keep the previous max angle
        float prevMaxAngle = m_RotationController.m_Head.m_MaxAngle;

        // lock the camera to the higher angle to avoid uncomfortable views (otherwise there may be a close-up on the buttocks)
        if (distance != maxDistance)
            m_RotationController.m_Head.m_MaxAngle = m_RotationController.m_Head.m_MinAngle;
        else
            m_RotationController.m_Head.m_MaxAngle = m_DefHeadMaxAngle;

        // max angle changed?
        if (prevMaxAngle != m_RotationController.m_Head.m_MaxAngle)
            // update the player rotation
            Rotate(new Vector2(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to move your player?

Comment: I published the source code containing the player movements. I simplified it as much as I could, but even thus it remains huge. Hope this will help. Otherwise I also own a complete working public project with the same issue, here: https://github.com/Jeanmilost/Unity/tree/master/3rd%20Person%20View